# How to use ClamAV to scan the memory

Tags: command-line, command, arguments, parameter, clamav

How can I only scan the computer RAM for viruses using the ClamAV command `clamscan`?

I already tried, because I found it on [ClamWin forum](http://forums.clamwin.com/viewtopic.php?p=8822#8822):

```
clamscan --memory
```

But it seems, that the Linux version does not have the argument `--memory`, because I can not find it in the help (`clamscan --help` or `man clamscan`).

If I try the command on Linux, I get:

```
~> clamscan --memory
clamscan: unrecognized option `--memory'
ERROR: Unknown option passed
ERROR: Can't parse command line options
```

I use Clam AntiVirus Scanner version 0.98.7.

Comment: Which version of ClamAV do you use? Maybe the version you have is just too old? Can you try with the most recent stable verion available for download on the official website?

Comment: my system has 0.99 installed and there is no such option for clamscan. i doubt that the newest version which is 0.99.1 has this option included. seems like this option is available for the windows version only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tested this in a docker container with an image of debian stretch.
https://packages.debian.org/source/stretch/clamav

The current stable version of Clamav for Linux is 0.99.1.
Source: https://www.clamav.net/

`clamscan` does not have such an option, I checked the manpage.

It seems that this option exists in the Windows version only.